# How to get full image paths from web page using Firebug?

Tags: image, server, directory, firebug

I would like to download all images in full quality from this blog: http://w899c8kcu.homepage.t-online.de/Blog.

I have access to server, but I can not find the directory where the images lie. When I use Firebug on the first picture, it shows me `http://w899c8kcu.homepage.t-online.de/Blog;session=f0577255d9df9185d3abe04af0ce922d&focus=CMTOI_de_dtag_hosting_hpcreator_widget_PictureGallery_15716702&path=image.action&frame=CMTOI_de_dtag_hosting_hpcreator_widget_PictureGallery_15716702?id=34877331&width=1000&height=2000&crop=false`.

How can I find the file paths like `/dirname/image.jpg`?

Comment: i don't now what you want to do exactly but try to open the pic in another windows and you will have the link or right click an copy the image location

Comment: I did this, but the link is as I gave. He wants to get the path to the file to be able to locate it on the server.

Comment: @OussemaAroua my problem is clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to its HTML output the page obviously uses the CM4all content management system (CMS).

I don't know how precisely this CMS is working, though generally CMSs normally either save the files under cryptic names within a folder specified in the CMS's configuration or not in the file system at all but within a database.

Also, CMS may only save compressed or resized versions of the original files.

So, if you don't want to or are not able to dig into the server-side script code to find out if and where the images are saved, you should [contact the company behind CM4all about this](https://www.cm4all.com/de/about-us/cm4all-contact/).